# Where does python's image_scraper library save images?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I want to save images scraped using image_scraper library of python to my current working directory. how can I do it? i tried but it is printing (0,0) to screen. what is that.
my code is.

```
import image_scraper
image_scraper.scrape_images("http://womaura.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/o-HAPPINESS-facebook-1.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a parameter called `download_path`. It is a good idea if you don't use an IDE like **PyCharm** to use the built-in `help` function to see the documentation for each function

```
>>> import image_scraper
>>> help(image_scraper.scrape_images)
Help on function scrape_images in module image_scraper.mains:

scrape_images(url, no_to_download=None, format_list=['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'svg', 'jpeg'], download_path='images', max_filesize=100000000, dump_urls=False, use_ghost=False)
```